# Single out everything after last occurence of a 10 number string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get everything from the start to the end of the last phone number (In short all contact information email and phone numbers).

```
'Firstname Lastname lorem@gmail.com 0000243598 CAB pilote 001 001',
'Firstname Lastname lorem@gmail.com 0100753503 CAB pilote 001 001',
'Firstname Lastname lorem@gmail.com 0033555381 0022243578 CAB pilote 001 001',
'Firstname Lastname lorem@gmail.com 0400253598 0000664248 CAB pilote 001 001',
```

So far, I already have a custom solution that is 10 foot long but I'm searching for something elegant along the lines of `\d{10,}(.*)$` tho, when a user has 2 phone numbers it fails to retrieve both.

I was hoping to single out "everything after the last occurence of a, at least, 10 numbers string, but failed to do so. Any help is welcome.

https://regex101.com/r/R32xC0/1

The `regex` has to be against the phone number has from time to time the stuff that comes after the last phone number change in length and content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading it right, and you want to

> I'm trying to get everything from the start to the end of the last
> phone number

Then you can match the `'` at the start of the string, and capture until the last occurrence of 10 or more digits in group 1.

```
^'(.* \d{10,})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A8LYic/1)

```js
const regex = /^'(.* \d{10,})/gm;
const str = `'Firstname Lastname lorem@gmail.com 0000243598 CAB pilote 001 001',
'Firstname Lastname lorem@gmail.com 0000243598 CAB pilote 001 001',
'Firstname Lastname lorem@gmail.com 0000243598 0000243598 CAB pilote 001 001',
'Firstname Lastname lorem@gmail.com 0000243598 0000243598 CAB pilote 001 001',`;

console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]));
```

If the quotes are not part of the string, then you can omit the group:

```
^.* \d{10,}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex in PCRE:

```sh
.*\h\K\d{10,}[^']*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/It4yai/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters (greedy match)
- `\h`: Match a whitespace
- `\K`: Reset the match
- `\d{10,}`: Match 10 or more digits
- `[^']*`: Match 0 or more of non-`'` characters

PS: If PCRE is not supported then use a capture group:

```
.*\s(\d{10,}[^']*)
```

Comment: It seems like the second phone number isn't included. I'm looking for a way to get `Firstname Lastname lorem@gmail.com 0033555381 0022243578` and `Firstname Lastname lorem@gmail.com 0000243598`. And my bad for not mentioning that i'm looking for a `javascript` regex solution.